# Javascript function not reachable after settimeout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have designed following code snippet:

```
                        <div id="content">
                            <h3>Select Images Below</h3>
                            <ul id="imagegallery">
                              <li>
                                <a class='a' href="./img/team/t1.jpg" title="The crowd goes wild" onclick="">
                                  <img src="./img/team/t1.jpg"  height="50px" width="50px" alt="the band in concert" />
                                </a>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <a class='a' href="./img/team/t2.jpg" title="An atmospheric moment">
                                  <img src="./img/team/t2.jpg" height="50px" width="50px" alt="the bassist" />
                                </a>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <a class='a' href="./img/team/t3.jpg" title="Rocking out">
                                  <img id='image' src="./img/team/t3.jpg" height="50px" width="50px" alt="the guitarist" />
                                </a>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <a class='a'href="./img/team/t4.jpg" title="Encore! Encore!">
                                  <img id='image' src="./img/team/t4.jpg" height="50px" width="50px" alt="the audience" />
                                </a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div>
                                <img id='placeholder', src="./img/resources/neutral_1.jpg", height="450px" width="550px" alt="Image gooes here", style="margin-bottom: 50px;padding: 10px;">
                            </div>
                            <div id="loading">
                                <img src="img/loading.gif" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div id="show">
                                <h1 id ='h'>It works</h1>
                            </div>
                          </div>
```

and the JS for this code is something like this

```
window.onload = function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      // Hide results
      document.getElementById('placeholder').style.display = 'none';
      // Show loader
      document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';
      setTimeout(showpic(this), 2000);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
  function showPic(whichpic) {
    document.getElementById('placeholder').style.display = 'block';
    var source = whichpic.getAttribute('href');
    var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
    placeholder.setAttribute('src', source);
    return false;
  }
};
```

I am trying to show the clicked image in the placeholder below,reading the source from href of a tags and assigning it to src of placeholder, but the problem  I am facing is that showpic is never called/reached. how should i modify my code to resolve this problem. I click the image, loader appears and then image loads in browser window

Comment: Do you have any errors in your DOM?

Comment: no, some warnings

Comment: `showpic(this)=>{}` doesn't look like valid syntax to me. I think you meant `() => { showpic(this); }`

Comment: @RobinZigmond, sorry for the typo, i was trying various ways for calling the function and mistakenly pasted it here, i edited the post now

Comment: Yeah, there's quite a few typos in your code that will cause some errors. `imageDescription` is wrong and `insertAfter` isn't defined at all as a function

Comment: Ok, i minimized my code to original, check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is not correct

```
setTimeout(showpic(this), 2000);
```

You should pass a function to `setTimeout` but you are calling it and actually passing some result of one's execution. You should do like this, for example

```
setTimeout(() => showpic(this), 2000);
```

2. You have a typo. You declare your function as `showPic` but call it as `showpic`

Comment: do you know some js library or snippet which shows the image in the div below in same page, instead of opening up a modal etc. My main goal is to click the thumbnail and enlarge it in the div below with some of details of image shown below

Answer (score 1):

Correct `showpic(this)` to `() => showpic(this)`.Your call to the `showPic` function is misspelled. Also your `showPic`function does not need to be wrapped inside of your `window.onload` function. Your JS should look like this and it should work:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      // Hide results
      document.getElementById('placeholder').style.display = 'none';
      // Show loader
      document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';
      setTimeout(() => showPic(this), 2000);
      e.preventDefault();
         });
    }
  }

function showPic(whichpic) {
    document.getElementById('placeholder').style.display = 'block';
    var source = whichpic.getAttribute('href');
    var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
    placeholder.setAttribute('src', source);
    return false;
  }
```